# Closing the active tab in IE using Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, internet-explorer

Does anyone know how to close the active tab of internet explorer using powershell?

I would like this to only close the tab (and not all tabs in the window).

Any Ideas would be appreciated

I have already tried

```
$ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" }
$ie.Quit()
```

However this closes all Tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ie` contains an array of all the open tabs, so it makes sense that when you invoke `Quit()` it will close all the open tabs.

If you specify the tab you want, it should work.

To close the last tab:

```
$ie[-1].Quit()
```

To close the first tab:

```
$ie[1].Quit()
```

To close a tab for a specific URL:

```
$ie.Where({ $_.LocationURL -eq "https://stackoverflow.com/" }).Quit()
```

The easiest way to find the active tab is the `MainWindowTitle` property from `Get-Process` which *should* roughly match up to the `LocationName` of one of the tabs.

```
$ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" }
$activeTab = ((Get-Process IExplore).MainWindowTitle | ? { $_ -ne "" }) -replace " - Internet Explorer"
$ie.Where({ $_.LocationName -eq $activeTab }).Quit()
```

**Note:** This will close all active tabs in Internet Explorer, each instance of the browser will have one active tab. If this is an issue, then you will need to isolate the instance of Internet Explorer you want to close the activeTab, each instance should have a unique `HWND`.